# WordPress: Exclude a parent page with get_pages()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages('exclude=10'); ?>
<?php foreach ( $pages as $page ) : ?>
    <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to *exclude* page id 10, but I would still like to *include* its subpages.

However if I try to include them with the `include` parameter, they still don’t show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several default ways [wp query to get child pages of current page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/wp-query-to-get-child-pages-of-current-page). but I will prefer this. You can use WordPress get_results() function and write an SQL query like this

```
global $wpdb;

$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p 
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'page' 
    AND p.post_parent LIKE 0 
    AND p.id NOT IN (
        SELECT post_parent 
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p 
        WHERE p.post_type = 'page' 
        AND p.post_parent != '0' 
        GROUP  BY post_parent
    )
");
```